# How to find class in in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to understand how basic things are working in eclipse in the code.

For example if I do hover on annotation or any change in the editor ( draw words )

How I can know which code of Java was called ( class.. )?

maybe could be some spy in eclipse to find code

Comment: Would it be easier and quicker to google it instead registering and asking question here? It's not really a programming problem - it's laziness.

Comment: @pivovarit Oh my god, how strict is this community sometimes. Don't you see this is the guys first question. The question is in place, since he is asking about a programming tool. Also there is a suggestion when he types the question that will tell him if the question is repeated already.

Comment: @user2444677 don't mind pivovarit; his opinions aren't representative of this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the mouse over a class type or return type for a couple of seconds the documentation will pop. If when it pops you put the mouse over it, after another second or 2 you will be able to scroll. Basically there is all the info about the class.

Some shortcuts you can use to interact with your classes are:

- Ctrl + 1 - See options for a methodCall or a selected snippet of code
- Ctrl + Shift + H - See call hierarchy for that method
- Ctrl + Alt + T is find Type it will help you quick find it.
- Shift + Alt + Q - See class outline view

For further reading you can see some of the most popular shortcuts people use. 
When you practice them a bit your life will be easier.
For further reading see this link: http://rayfd.me/2007/05/20/10-eclipse-navigation-shortcuts-every-java-programmer-should-know/

Comment: I mean for something generic in eclipse like when I do over then I can see textbox. How eclipse do it ?Can I find the classes of java ?

Comment: @user2444677 I am not sure what do you mean? When you press `Ctrl + Space` you will see also some suggestions in a box(I am not sure if is that what you mean). To find classes you have to use the shortcut I told you above `Ctrl + Alt + T`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to find out a class declaration:

   `F3 (Windows)`

   `Fn + F3 (Mac)`
2. If you want to find a reference of a given variable in a file:

   `Ctrl + Shift + U (Windows)`

   `Command + Shift + U (Mac)`
3. If you want to find a reference of a given variable in the workspace:

   `Ctrl + Shift + G (Windows)`

   `Command + Shift + G (Mac)`

Comment: I mean for something generic in eclipse like when I do over then I can see textbox. How eclipse do it ?Can I find the classes of java ?

Comment: When you hover over the class name, what you see is the Java doc.  If you dive into that class, using F3.  You can see the annotation, which generates the Java doc.

Comment: I don't want to do hover on class name but to do hover on the folding ( colpase,expend ) and then I want to find the eclipse code.

Comment: it is generic example . I want to find class of eclipse to understand how the build eclipse and the functionality